# Does Tor take node age into consideration when building a circuit?

Tags: relays, circuit, client, protocol

I've seen this for a while, but in my experience Tor seems to select well stablished nodes (whose uptime is >60 days) but in [the specifications](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/114/475) this is not shown. It's just that the current list of nodes doesn't grow/chage? Or is there some other mechanism in play?

Comment: The answer is probably [here](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay) but I'm not the one to translate it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the §2.2 "Path selection and constraints" of the [Path Spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob_plain/6f2919a2ede935b8783e1fa93178ebb425b54f17:/path-spec.txt) (as of commit [6f2919a2](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/commit/6f2919a2ede935b8783e1fa93178ebb425b54f17)):

> Additionally, we may be building circuits with one or more requests in
>   mind.  Each kind of request puts certain constraints on paths:
>
> - All service-side introduction circuits and all rendezvous paths
>     should be Stable.
> - All connection requests for connections that we think will need to
>     stay open a long time require Stable circuits.  Currently, Tor decides
>     this by examining the request's target port, and comparing it to a
>     list of "long-lived" ports. (Default: 21, 22, 706, 1863, 5050,
>     5190, 5222, 5223, 6667, 6697, 8300.)

A "stable" node is defined in §3.1 "Establishing server status" of the [dir spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob_plain/6f2919a2ede935b8783e1fa93178ebb425b54f17:/dir-spec-v2.txt) as:

> "Stable" -- A router is 'Stable' if it is active, and either its
>   uptime is at least the median uptime for known active routers, or its
>   uptime is at least 30 days. Routers are never called stable if they
>   are running a version of Tor known to drop circuits stupidly.
>   (0.1.1.10-alpha through 0.1.1.16-rc are stupid this way.)

Stable nodes are also required in several other places, so it's likely that you'll often pick nodes with high uptimes when building circuits.

Comment: As Sam mentions, age (in fact, weighted uptime) matters. If you find the specification a bit of a dry read, it is explained (from the point of view of a node) here : https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay