# Does traffic exit Tor at the same node for all ports?

Tags: exit-relays, circuit, client, exit-policies

Exit Relays can be set to allow traffic to exit the Tor network only over certain ports. Vidalia even makes this super-simple by giving options like "Normal, unencrypted Web browsing" or "IRC clients and servers".

[This answer](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/231/71) notes that:

> Tor chooses an exit relay which actually allows you to exit the Tor
>   network. Some only allow web traffic (port 80) which is not useful
>   when someone wants to send emails.

What happens when a  user is passing traffic over multiple ports? It wouldn't be uncommon to receive email over IMAP whilst web browsing, or even to visit a page serving a mix of HTTP & HTTPS content. Would Tor have to find a single Exit Relay which allows all ports needed, or is it possible that traffic might exit a different node for each port?

Answer (score 4):

No. Tor traffic does not necessarily all exit at the same exit node.

For each socket connection that the client sets up, a circuit is used that ends in an appropriate exit node. That is an exit node that allows the IP and port the client is trying to reach.