# Fast/Slow relays in Tor

Tags: relays, circuit, bandwidth, fast-relays

1. How does Tor classify fast/slow relays (as in what is the bandwidth bar)?
2. Is the Tor Path Selection protocol biased towards selecting fast relays for circuit construction? (The answer here [How does a Tor client pick Tor nodes for circuit creation?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/113/how-does-a-tor-client-pick-tor-nodes-for-circuit-creation/231#231) states the bias but I am unsure if this is still the case.)

I am still trying to find my answers here (https://github.com/torproject/torspec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. From the [directory spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt), the threshold is almost always 100 KB/s.

   > A router is 'Fast' if it is active, and its bandwidth is either in the top 7/8ths for known active routers or at least 100KB/s.
2. Yes the Tor path selection algorithm is weighted by relays' consensus weights and is described in the [path spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/path-spec.txt) document.

The actual way that these numbers are calculated is not straightforward. For example, bandwidths for flags are computed by the function [`dirserv_get_credible_bandwidth_kb()`](https://github.com/torproject/tor/blob/4f114f59e62397fba98b17e1394adfa29e3de78b/src/feature/dirauth/bwauth.c#L172) which depends on the measured and advertised bandwidths (and the advertised bandwidth depends on the observed bandwidth). The threshold for the `Fast` flag is computed in [`dirserv_compute_performance_thresholds()`](https://github.com/torproject/tor/blob/4f114f59e62397fba98b17e1394adfa29e3de78b/src/feature/dirauth/voteflags.c#L231). Consensus weights also have a complicated calculation which you can find in the "3.8.3. Computing Bandwidth Weights" section of the directory spec document.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @ArushiArora I updated the answer slightly, I misread "or at least 100KB/s" as "and at least 100KB/s". So the `Fast` flag requires a bandwidth of only 100 KB/s.