# Tor connection from 1st to 2nd computer, then from 2nd computer, a 2nd Tor connection to browse web (for increased untraceability)

Tags: anonymity, vpn, ssh, ssl, virtual-machine

Requirement: set up a two-leg Tor connection (using Tor twice). End user works on 1st computer, connects thru Tor to a 2nd off-site computer (could go thru VPN, SSH, or SSL as well), and then from that 2nd computer, goes thru Tor a second time to browse the web anonymously.

Intended purpose: to increase the level of untraceability and anonymity. The set up is this:

End user on 1st Computer > Tor Connection > 2nd Off-site Computer > 2nd Tor Connection > Browse the Web

The 2nd computer is at an off-site location, and the 2nd computer would be impossible to trace back to the end user, even if it were found. So this means if the 2nd Tor connection (between the 2nd computer and the websites being browsed) gets hacked, only the 2nd off-site computer will be found, but not the 1st computer.

So this set up uses Tor twice in 2 legs as a double precaution against being traced. This set up is like using Tor with a virtual machine, but using a physical 2nd computer in place of a virtual machine, and using Tor twice, in two legs.

What is the best way to set this up? Any suggestions?

The 2nd computer will be a Windows 10 or Android device.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. Try Tor over VPN or JAP or (chained) proxies or something else.
[Is running Tor over Tor dangerous?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/433/4894)

Comment: What about a setup where I install a clean offsite computer at a remote location, and run the Tor browser on that remote computer as per normal. Then I connect to that remote computer using VNC screen sharing. The network traffic patterns should be quite different, since a VNC connection sends the screen image displayed on the the remote computer over the Internet.

Comment: It should be OK as long as your VNC setup is secure. You can also try using a public proxy (whether chained or not) instead of a Tor instance on the 2nd computer (then you must use Tor on your own computer).

Answer (score 1):

Your second computer must have two separate ISP's with different IP addresses, and it should be no problem at all : you will use two virtual machines, one for "using net securely", you will connect to it's VNC through Tor for a first time via first Internet connection, and this VM will go outside through a second VM, that will be a Tor router, WAN-bridged to a second Internet connection.

Comment: With two separate ISPs and different IPs, will this prevent Internet traffic analysis that could be traced back to me?

Comment: @vatva yes it will, if properly done