# Is it possible to change the default circuit length?

Tags: circuit, whonix

Default number of nodes is 3. Can i build a circuit of 5 or 6 nodes? (using whonix)

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to compile Tor from source - this is not a configuration change.

However, this isn't a great decision - [Is it possible to make the Tor onion-routing path longer?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/103/is-it-possible-to-make-the-tor-onion-routing-path-longer) has a few answers about this topic.

Comment: Ok. That increase the probability to get a bad node, but if you are using a bridge registered in BridgeDB then you are pretty sure your first hop is good, no way to know your real IP. then, all is encrypted to the exit node. so even if you have a bad node in your circuit (except exit) , he just see encrypted traffic, isn't it?  increasing number of node as you use a bridge doesn't affect anonymity to me. maybe i'm wrong?

Comment: @user1698, Dear, Using bridges, while you can use regular guards is a bad idea. Bridges are not testes as truly as regular guards and in addition bridges are more severely under surveillance than regular guards by global adversary. Bridges are meant to be the last resort in case you can not use regular guards due to censorship. They are used for circumvention but you will most likely lose your anonymity if you use them. For reference read the following article. http://daserste.ndr.de/panorama/aktuell/NSA-targets-the-privacy-conscious,nsa230.html

Answer (score 0):

While this would not not necessarily affect your anonymity it would make tor slower and eat more node bandwidth. This means there would be no real gain, only more unnecesary issues.