# tor relays question?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, relays, middle

I read this in some book :

> All  connections  between  the  first  relay  and  the  exit  relay 
>   are  encrypted,  and each  relay along  the  way knows  only the 
>   previous  and  the  next hop.  No  one  knows  the complete pathway in
>   this architecture, except attacks which reveal some of them

The first question:

he said no one knows the whole path, but the middle relay know the previous and the next so, this is the full path, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The middle knows the *entry* and *exit nodes*, but does not know

- who connects to Tor
- whom does it connect to.

Answer (score -1):

And - take a look at my patch [here](https://github.com/netsafe/tor-patches/blob/master/tor-route-length.patch) - and it's not the only way to make all the nodes have no way to map a path

Comment: This patch increases the number of hops from 3 to 7, which is [recommended against](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChoosePathLength), and isn't proven to increase security. (This [paper](http://freehaven.net/anonbib/#ccs07-doa) also explains why longer paths can hurt your anonymity, rather than increase it.)

Comment: This thread also references that paper: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/103/is-it-possible-to-make-the-tor-onion-routing-path-longer

Comment: @RichardHorrocks It depends on how many people use this patch ;) Also - in the particular case - the problem is in Tor protocol itself.'