# Change default circuit length?

Tags: configuration

In AdvOR I can set circuit length.
Can I set it in normal tor configuration file?

i read tor faq , and i dont find answer.
https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorFAQ

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make the Tor onion-routing path longer?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/103/is-it-possible-to-make-the-tor-onion-routing-path-longer)

Comment: P.S. I'd recommend against AdvOR, I read it's source code changes and whoever wrote it should never be allowed to write C code. It has some glaringly bad flaws and bugs in it.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's hardcoded inside tor's sources. Setting the circuit length is not as simple as it is spelled: developing this setting I've seen quite a pack of challenges:

- Using statically changed path length has it's uses sometimes, I did the patch for it first and released it [here on GitHub](https://github.com/netsafe/tor-patches/blob/master/tor-route-length.patch) - but keep in mind, that using it as it is reduces your anonymity: your traffic can be a bit easier to determine, bu yes - it rises the encryption strength due to more layers elaborated
- Using conditional path length is **not that simple** on a binary-level, and it has required me to rewrite quite a bunch of Tor's code. This patch will be released later with my solution.

For now - if you need to set the longer path somewhere - you should use Stem or other Tor control protocol clients to construct the custom circuits for your very paricular tasks

Comment: Were you ever able to get dynamic default path lengths working?